# Storing static content (strings) outside application - WP7

Tags: c#, xml, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'm trying to store my static strings in such a way that they can be edited without recompiling. These strings are a bunch of URLs used for querying the server with web requests and it would be nice to put them in an xml file named config or settings for easy access. I know on Android this is easy to do with an xml file that looks something like:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <resources>

       <string name="hello">Hello World!</string>
       ...
       ...

   </resources>
```

And if it was stored in res/values/strings.xml then I can just reference it like R.string.hello from my activity.

Is there a way to do this on the windows phone? or using a standard windows way of saving configuration information so it can be edited without recompiling?

Thanks in advance for your helpful comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff637520%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) for this purpose.

Comment: Yah just found that out, most other platforms have their resources separate from the binarys but this is Microsoft's way of doing config files so I guess it will have to work. If I wanted to be able to replace resources on the fly as I described, I'd have to implement my own resource loading mechanism which isn't desirable.

Comment: I'm just curious how would  you implement the replacement mechanism? The only way I see is to load the resources over the Internet. But in this case it's better to create a strong-typed class which represents data you need.

Comment: @AndreiSchneider I have no idea how I would implement it and I've decided not to spend time thinking about it since I'm going with the .resx file instead, abandoning all hopes of a normal config file.